# Recurring (but probably erroneous) error message in glmmADMB package

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

I am getting the same message over and over again in the glmmADMB package; however I think it may be erroneous since all the values I am getting when I run the different models on the `Owls` dataset agree with the output published in the glmmADMB manual.

The message reads

```
Warning message:
In .local(x, sigma, ...) :
  'sigma' and 'rdig' arguments are present for compatibility only: ignored
```

The software package creator Ben Bolker seems to suggest that it is spurious [here](https://github.com/bbolker/glmmadmb/blob/master/R/methods.R) and, from what I gather, wrote some code to suppress the warning. But I don't know how to implement these debugs. Any help appreciated.